# Simple audio engine not playing audio on actual device. Plays it on simulator though

Tags: audio, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I am trying to integrate background music into my cocos2d game using simple audio engine.

I use the playBackgroundMusic method of simple audio engine

here is the line of code I use:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playBackgroundMusic:@"Soundtrack.mp3" loop:YES];
```

I also imported the SimpleAudioEngine header file. I have the code in my GameEngine class.

Comment: You must pose a problem and ask a related question you need answering. So far you have only made a statement.

Comment: show code if you want any help on such an issue.

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to play `Soundtrack.mp3` make sure the file is actually named `Soundtrack.mp3` and not `soundtrack.mp3` or `SoundTrack.mp3`.

The iOS file system is case sensitive. The Mac's (Simulator's) file system is not. Ergo it will play on the Simulator but not on the device. Case matters.